# Reading from a textfile in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have recently tried to read from a textfile and populate the db and then display the populated data onto my MVC application. Reason for all of this is because I want my desktop application to be able to pass data to my MVC application and save it into my MVC db.

This is what I have:

```
public ActionResult Index([Bind(Include = "location_id,location_name")] Location location)
    {
        string full_path = Request.MapPath("~/App_Data/TestText.txt");
        if (System.IO.File.Exists(full_path))
        {
            if (new System.IO.FileInfo(full_path).Length > 0)
            {
                string[] text_file = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(HostingEnvironment.MapPath(@"~/App_Data/TestText.txt"));
                foreach (string record in text_file)
                {
                    string[] record_cell = record.Split('~');
                    location.location_name = record_cell[1];
                    db.Locations.Add(location);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                }

                System.IO.File.WriteAllText(HostingEnvironment.MapPath(@"~/App_Data/TestText.txt"), "");
            }
        }

        ViewBag.location_id = new SelectList(db.Locations, "location_id", "location_name");

        return View();
    }
```

I have the code above which is placed in my home controller so that everytime the page loads it looks into the textfile for new data and stores it in the db, and at the same time returns a view to display the index page.

Everything works fine on localhost however when hosted I am getting the following error:

> [image: Screenshot - Error]

I have my textfile located in App_Data, I however feel as though placing the code in the controller under Index is causing this. Can you please help me out to show me where to place the code so that on startup of the website it checks for updated datab in the textfile.

Update:

I have found the error causing the site not to load. Somehow the following line of code from the view, which is populating a dropdown list with data from the db is not working:

```
@Html.DropDownList("location_id", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control"})
```

Any solutions on fixing this?

Comment: You need to debug the application and tell us what exact error it is giving at what exact line. This is not a clear problem statement which can only lead to guessing.

Comment: You can use breakpoints and catch block to reveal stack trace and line position where the error occurs. Then, include it in your question.